Buying tires: how do you choose the brand and model
I need to buy four tires for my car. I go on the Costco website and the prices go from $230 (Michelin - Pilot Sport 4 SUV) to $163 (BFGoodrich - Advantage Control) each, with lots in between. I live in South Carolina with no winter. My inclination is this: these are just tires, BFGoodrich is a "known" brand, why would I need to pay any more than the lowest price? Any recommendation on what I should be looking at when choosing a tire will be welcome.

Here in the UK, tyres are all given ratings in three categories - wet grip, noise and fuel economy. IMHO the wet grip ratio is most important, so I'd never choose one with a rating below 'B' there (they go from A to G, in the same way as our appliance efficiency ratings do). Do you have something similar over there?
Reviews can also be useful these days, especially if you can find some from people with similar cars and climate to yourself.
Finally I usually ignore the cheapest (which are usually no-name 'ditchfinders' in our tyre shops) and go for something about a third of the way up the cost bracket - which the last few times has been something from Uniroyal or Toyo.

For me, braking in the wet is by far the most important factor. Noise is less important if your journeys are mostly urban (low speed). In UK we also have a rule about unfixable punctures near the edge, and with low usage the rubber can degrade before the tread has worn out, and so I often have to scrap a tyre before it has worn out anyway. I never buy expensive tyres, but the best budget ones, many of which perform just as well. I buy online and book an appointment, meaning I am not under pressure to make a decision, and my chosen tyre will be in stock.

It depends on your driving style too: a sporty grippy tyre can wear out quickly and the true cost can be much greater than is apparent from the bare pricing.

Hey guys, at first, I was bummed to get an "English" response because I live in the US, and things are different. But, thanks to both of you, I looked at ratings and it turns out that there is something called "UTQG" ratings about Temperature, Traction, and Treadwear. Also, your general recommendations on how to buy a tire make a lot of sense. The rating system is all explained here for example: https://www.prioritytire.com/blog/what-is-utqg-tire-ratings-explained/

Thanks @Gateauaufromage - I figured that even if you didn't have an official rating system, chances are someone would have done similar tests or comparisons you could use. Plus many of the tyres are probably the same the world over...
